# How to remove freq='W-FRI' portion in Timestamp

Tags: pandas, datetime, time, timestamp, finance

okay so I have two data frames both with datetime as indices.

When I call df1 index, I get:

```
df1.index[0]
Timestamp('2016-03-04 00:00:00')
```

when I call df2 index, i get:

```
df2.index[0]
Timestamp('2016-03-11 00:00:00', freq='W-FRI')
```

I'm trying to remove the freq='W-FRI' part. I want my second data frame (df2) to return the follow when I call for the first index:

```
df2.index[0]
Timestamp('2016-03-03 00:00:00')
```

Thanks so much. This small difference is not allowing me to index my data frames with dates.

Comment: So in addition to removing the `freq` part, you need it to shift the dates forward by 8 days, or is that a typo?

Answer (score 6):

You have a DatetimeIndex with a `freq`. Set it to `None`

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='W-FRI', periods=10)
idx[0]
#Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00', freq='W-FRI')

idx.freq=None
idx[0]
#Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00')
```

---

All `DatetimeIndex` objects have a frequency attribute, the default is `None`.

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2011-01-02'])
#DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2011-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```